# On Becoming Excellence

Tags: grammar, word-choice, nouns, adjectives

I'm trying to come up with an interesting title for a self-help type of blog and I've fallen on the name in the title but I don't know whether it's grammatically correct. I don't need perfection but if it is technically able to be used and doesn't break English grammar rules then that's OK!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is only 'correct' if it expresses what you want to say. Which is...?

Comment: Enroute to Excellence! On Becoming Excellence seems to be talking about "One's views upon becoming excellent".  If you are fine with it, it works.

Comment: 'On becoming excellence' really implies that you find 'They are excellence' acceptable. Unqualified, I don't.

Comment: One does not become excellence (though excellence may become one).

Answer (score 0):

"On Becoming Excellence" sounds fine to me, especially for a blog title. Actually though, it would sound better if you left out the "on", and just make it "Becoming Excellence".

Comment: Yeah, in this context it implies "becoming the personification of excellence".

Comment: This answer only works if, as Hotlicks says, it is a _personification_.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what grammatical gymnastics can be done to excuse this title I cannot recommend them. Learning to write, even for a blog, means learning to give up what you may have fallen in love with. Having a grammatically clunky title could not advance your blog's popularity. There are lovely answers waiting to love you back.

One may be or become excellent, not excellence. So; *On becoming Excellent* but I can see that you wish to use the word Excellence.

Closer to perfection would be *On Achieving Excellence*.

You are on your way.